# Constructing triangle using side length-median relationship

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

$$\begin{align}
m^2_a&=\frac{2b^2+2c^2−a^2}4\\[4pt]
m^2_b&=\frac{2c^2+2a^2−b^2}4\\[4pt]
m^2_c&=\frac{2a^2+2b^2−c^2}4
\end{align}$$

Solving for $a$, $b$, $c$ in terms of $m^2_a$, $m^2_b$, $m^2_c$ gives:

$$\begin{align}
a^2&=\frac{8m^2_b+8m^2_c−4m^2_a}9 \\[4pt]
b^2&=\frac{8m^2_c+8m^2_a−4m^2_b}9 \\[4pt]
c^2&=\frac{8m^2_a+8m^2_b−4m^2_c}9
\end{align}$$

How can I construct a general triangle using this information?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need explicitly find the lengths of the sides. Just build a triangle having side lengths $2m_a,2m_b,2m_c$ (the red one in the picture), find its centroid and draw a few parallel lines to the medians:
[image: Medians hexagon]

The hexagon is made of six congruent triangles with side lengths $a,b,c$.

Comment: I know I do not need to explicitly find the lengths of the sides, otherwise I know of other constructions. Using the information gathered from finding the lengths of the sides, I'd like to construct a triangle from that.

Comment: If you know the side lengths $a,b,c$, what else do you need to construct a triangle?

Comment: For a general case, without a,b,c known. So, basically using the algebraic formulation to relate the side lengths and the medians, I wanted to construct a triangle from known medians, but not known side lengths.

Comment: But your formulas give that if you know the median lengths you also know /are able to build the side lengths.